# Media scanning specific folder

Tags: android, android-mediascanner

I'm finding a media scanning source that can scan files in specific folder.
Or source that scans specific extension files (Like .mp4) in specific folder.
Thanks.

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Editted.

Comment: and what is your progress?where is your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code to get the files from specific folder:

```
File folder_file = new File("give specific folder path");
    File[] files = folder_file.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (File file : files) {
            // checking the File is file or directory
            if (file.isFile()) {
                String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
                String extension = path
                        .substring(path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                // if the file is audio type, then save it to the database
                if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("mp4")) {
                    System.out.println(path + " is a media file ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Try this for scanning files:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri
                    .parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: Is it a media scanning source?

Comment: Do u want to get the media files list or only scanning files?

Comment: For the record, setting uri file data to just the parent directory worked for me. Iterating across the directory and sending a broadcast for each file did not work.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm finding a media scanning source that can find files in specific
>   folder

[MediaScannerConnection.scanFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29) takes second parameter as String Array of paths to be scanned

> source that scans specific extension files (Like .mp4) in specific
>   folder.

[MediaScannerConnection.scanFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29) takes third parameter as String Array of `mimeTypes` which we want to scan.

Example:

```
String[] paths = {path_to_scan};
String[] mimeTypes = {"video/mp4"};
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(),
                                paths,
                                mimeTypes,
                              new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                               public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                 // scanned path and uri
                              }
                         });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934159/mediastore-not-working-when-folder-programmatically-created can you check this.please help to get out from it