# Media Store not working when folder programmatically created

Tags: java, android, file, mediastore

I am accessing `videos`, from programmatically created folder, using following code But it returning cursor count `0`, what should I do to solve this problem.

I have tested it on some devices, this is not perfect solution.
looking for better one, can anyone help me?

```
 String selection=MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA +" like?";
        String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{"%smartVcall%"};
        videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                parameters, selection, selectionArgs, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```

To create folder I am using following code

```
 File moviesDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/smartVcall");
        if (!moviesDir.exists()) {
            moviesDir.mkdirs();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should force the Android `MediaStore` to index created directory.

```
String directoryPath = "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/smartVcall"
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse(directoryPath)));
```